# Flutter - How to pause qr scan reading

Tags: flutter

I'm developing a qr scan app. And using qr_code_scanner 0.5.2.

When i scan a qr code, my app jump to another page with the scanned code, but the app still scanning the qr codes and new pages appears until you d not focus on any qr code.

How can i scan codes one by one and pause scanning while on the another page and resume scanning when the new page is closed?

Thanks

code:

```
  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
setState(() {
  this.controller = controller;
});
controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) {
  setState(() {
    controller.pauseCamera();
    Navigator.push(context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return ReadData(data: scanData.code);
      }),
    );
    controller.resumeCamera();
  });
});
```

}

edit:
solution code:

```
  void _onQRViewCreated(QRViewController controller) {
  this.controller = controller;

controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData) async {
 
  controller.pauseCamera();
  await Navigator.push(
    context,
    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return ReadData(data: scanData.code);
    }),
  );
  
  controller.resumeCamera();
});
```

}

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`qr_code_scanner` controller got a method called  `pauseCamera` use that to pause camera whenever a valid barcode is detected.

edit: if `pauseCamera` is not working then you can add boolean variable and switch it to true whenever you get valid QR code. And, navigate to new page only if this variable is false.

I've updated the code, Please take a look.

```
...
bool gotValidQR = false; //toggle this value when you got a new qr code
...
controller.scannedDataStream.listen((scanData)async {
    if(gotValidQR) {
      return;
    }
    gotValidQR = true;
    dynamic pop = await Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
        return ScannedData(data: scanData.code);
      }),
    );
    gotValidQR  = false;
});
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The pausing is okay, i did the same, but i cant restart it. I used this code, but its not work, because this do not stop the scanning. I updated the original post.

Comment: @Scarg I've updated the code, please try that method

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its nearly works. Your code is stopped the new page popup, but in the background still scanning, so i add the pause and resume after the validQr and its works fine. Thanks (I updated the original post with the solution code.)

Comment: I made more tests, and my original code works fine with async and await. Thanks